# How can I force several variables included in the regression in r just like include=n option in SAS

Tags: r, model, sas, regression

SAS MODEL Statement introduction
INCLUDE=n
forces the first n independent variables listed in the MODEL statement to be included in all models. The selection methods are performed on the other variables in the MODEL statement. The INCLUDE= option is not available with SELECTION=NONE.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will find that R users are mostly averse (on solid theoretic grounds) to mimicking SAS's stepwise regression functions. However, you will find that `step` argument `scope` has an 'upper' and a 'lower' option and you probably should first read the `?step`-help page and then create a value for 'lower'.

> scope
>   defines the range of models examined in the stepwise search. This should be either a single formula, or a list containing components upper and lower, both formulae. See the details for how to specify the formulae and how they are used.